# SQL-query in arcpy - SELECT WHERE feature between two values

Tags: python, arcpy, sql, query

I need to select features between two values in python with arcpy. However, whenever I try to run the code below, it returns with error message "An invalid SQL statement was used".

```
whereclause = """"X" BETWEEN {0} AND {1}""".format(
                                                  min(X)[0]-1000,
                                                  max(X)[0]+1000)
ap.FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion(SamledeMaalinger,ap.env.workspace,"SamledeMaalingerSort", whereclause)
```

The whereclause returns *"X" BETWEEN 555157.0723 AND 557157.0723* so it's not the string that's the issue.

The SQL-query works if I use < and > instead, but the BETWEEN for some reason doesn't.

So what's the issue? Do the SQL-queries in arcpy have limitations?

Comment: where do you store the gdb?

Comment: According to [About building an SQL expression](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.2/index.cfm?TopicName=About_building_an_SQL_expression) you should be able to use BETWEEN: _You can use greater than (>), less than (<), greater than or equal (>=), less than or equal (<=), and BETWEEN operators_

Comment: perhaps failing because the numbers are being compared as strings instead when BETWEEN used, while `<` forces numeric(?)

Answer (score 1):

As @AlexTereshnekov commented, the problem may be caused by your spatial data storage choice.

I just used the expression below successfully in a file geodatabase feature class:

```
OID BETWEEN 1 AND 100
```

but in a shapefile this expression reported that it was invalid SQL:

```
"FID" BETWEEN 1 AND 100
```

My testing used ArcGIS 10.2.2 for Desktop